# How to add .js file to netsuite SCA Denali / Mont-Blanc

Tags: netsuite

I am currently editing a Netsuite SCA implementation - and need to add a .js file to the site.

In SiteBuilder this was fairly simple with editing templates. However, with SCA it looks like we need quite a bit more configuration to make it happen.

I'd welcome some help from the community on how to add a .js file.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a third party module create a new directory for it under `Modules/third_parties/MyModule@1.0.0`

If its a custom javascript file create a new folder under `Modules/MyCustomModules/MyModule@1.0.0`

Create a JavaScript folder under `MyModule@1.0.0/JavaScript` and place your file in there.

Create a `ns.package.json` file at the root of `MyModule@1.0.0`, with the following contents:

```
{
    "gulp": {
        "javascript": [
            "JavaScript/*"
        ]
    },
    "jshint": "false"
}
```

Open the distro.json file at the root of the SCA application and add your module to the modules object:

If you added your module to thrid_parties use:

`"third_parties/MyModule":"1.0.0"`

If you added a new MyCustomModules folder use:

`"MyCustomModules/MyModule":"1.0.0"`

Then add `MyModule` to the dependencies object in the `distro.json` for each application. E.g. if you only use the js file in the shopping application, add it to the dependencies object for the `SC.Shopping.Starter` entrypoint.

Then `gulp deploy` to deploy your new module

Comment: If my custom ka include Ajax call then how should I use the call before page load..

Comment: For example I have maxmind ka file which give me response in sucess but if I tried to add this in starter file then it gives me response late

Comment: Im assuming the problem you are having is because the call is asynchronous. You will need to adopt your code to handle the async response.

Comment: got that. Thanks